# Python request handling two cookies with same name

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I am working on making a login process automate for [this](https://www.bsesdelhi.com/web/bypl/login) using python using below code.

```
import requests
first_url = "https://www.bsesdelhi.com/web/bypl/login"
response = requests.request("GET", first_url)
print(response.cookies)
```

Output of above code is :

```
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID=en_US for .bsesdelhi.com/>, <Cookie TS0104a5ce=01cb274fca75fcb82f5ab68ba663e51b42646c615a74e619405278fee3b6adeedf599b086c5a0e2245a41954e8975e1b732ab9554c77ff958f24bb67b91a620c00287c3da53e2be86037d184f22f30e73e478e8b80cda39c769d03edb6184212d5940eda66f73416f7d0a36318883e1835ee666067a9997a2b9e66210f9135a64de10873df for .bsesdelhi.com/>, 
<Cookie COOKIE_SUPPORT=true for www.bsesdelhi.com/>, <Cookie JSESSIONID=.node1 for www.bsesdelhi.com/>, <Cookie ROUTEID=.node1 
for www.bsesdelhi.com/>]>
```

But when I hit the same url from browser it gives two cookies with same name **JSESSIONID**. But seems like request only gives second cookie. Below is the screenshot from browser

[image]

I want to use another cookie *JSESSIONID* the one which is missing in response.cookies for subsequent call. How can I do that?

I already tried to use session also. But that lead to same condition.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: this seems to be in the response header. try `response.headers['Set-Cookie']`